# Assigning luminance Y to color R for writing single-channel EXR files with OpenCV-Python

Tags: python, opencv, openexr

I am processing texture maps for Unreal Engine 5 with OpenCV-Python, but I've encountered a problem with single-channel 16-bit EXR images, e.g. opacity mask maps, that are saved with only a Y luminance channel. UE5 does not read the Y channel, which results in a black image. However, it will read single-channel EXRs with just an R, G, or B channel. I want to convert the Y channel of these EXRs and save them with only R without storing G and B channels in the metadata. If only a single channel is loaded, imwrite() will save an EXR with just Y in the metadata.

I have tried merging empty numpy arrays for G and B, and while this is better than copying R into G and B, this still results in a larger file than just storing a single channel. Are there any ways to achieve writing an EXR with just R with OpenCV?

Comment: perhaps you need a different library, one that gives you this level of control. OpenCV is for computer vision, not for saving images flexibly. -- look into imagemagick. it's a command line tool. or maybe this can be fixed from inside of UE5.

Comment: You're probably right. I am using OpenCV for other things before this point, and if it is possible to do, I'd prefer to keep everything in OpenCV. It worked great for other images, but we now need more flexibility. It looks like the OpenImageIO library can do what I need and has python bindings.